# Conflito entre Modal (chamando pagina remota) e dropdown-menu

Tags: bootstrap, modal, dropdown, with

Bom dia Galera !
Estou com um conflito entre o menu dropdopwn e o modal chamando um pagina remota.

eu tenho uma pagina chamada lista.php que tem o dropdown-menu e dentro deste um li que chama o modal abrindo remotante o formulario.php

quando clico no link do menu o modal abre normalmente

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
<a href="formulario.php?id=<?=$Id?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_formulario">
Alterar 
</a>
</li>
```

porém ao fechar o modal usando o código abaixo, o menu simplesmente para de funcionar.

```
<a href="#" class="btn red" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
Fechar 
</a>
```

Eu já percebi que o problema é que nas duas paginas eu tenho uma chamada ao bootstrap.min.js

Se eu retiro essa chamada do formulario.php, o menu dropdown que esta em lista.php funciona perfeitamente, abrindo e fechando o modal ! 
Porém as dentro do formulario.php param de funcionar os efeitos de validacao de formulario que utilizam o bootstrap...

Como resolver este conflito ?

Comment: Essas paginas estão online? pode passar o link? Tomara que eu esteja enganado mas acho que só com essas infos fica difícil  alguém descobrir algo

Comment: Infelizmente nao posso te passar o acesso pq é uma intranet de uma empresa... mas ficou alguma dúvida na explicacao ?

Comment: Pois é, olhando o codigo fonte daria para estudar melhor o problema